Unable to authenticate into a Web Form ASP.NET site after publishing/deployment on the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
We have a strange and extreme problem when publishing our latest code from Test/UAT region to a production region.
After publishing to a production the authentication stops working, users cannot login to a site. What is more shocking, we cannot revert the code. Bringing the old code back doesn't solve the authentication issue.
We had a crisis during the production core hours and and fixed it with the entire server backup of couple of days earlier
Later on Friday night we attempted another migration, and the authentication stopped working again.
We cleaned the folder, restored it by placing the previously backed up files into that folder, but the authentication stayed broken.
We compared folder permissions between the test server and the production server. Synced those permissions, the authentication still didn't work.
We did other comparisons between production and test, everything seemed to be identical, still the users couldn't authenticate in a production environment
We restored the site not from the latest backup, but from the backup previous to the latest, authentication started working.
Web.config files were identical in the latest backup and the backup previous to the latest backup.
We do have .NET 4.8 confirmed by this command:
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse 
    | Get-ItemProperty -Na me version -EA 0
    | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} 
    | Select PSChildName, version

I get this output:
PSChildName Version
----------- ------- 
Client      4.8.03761  
Full        4.8.03761   
Client      4.0.0.0

We have these authentication settings in the web.config:
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" path="/" requireSSL="true" timeout="15" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />

We run our site on Windows 2016 Datacenter.
Can anyone suggest any area we could explore so that the authentication can be a bit more stable?
Thank you everyone in advance
These are the authentication settings in the IIS, we have forms and anonymous authentication both enabled



Can the new server connect to the database used for logons? Looking at that setting, it looks like you using FBA (forms based authenticaiton). That means in the web config, there must be a area with some connection strings, and one of those connection strings is going to point to a database used for logons. Can the server reach that database used for logons? So, best guess (and it is a guess), then would be to look at the connection strings, and that the database used for logons can't be reached. That is the first thing I would look at.

Thank you for your comment, yes it is, our public site is working and the db connection strings are identical between test and production server, the also the connection string is identical to the backup which fixed the authentication issue after a restoration

But you not confirmed if the new server can reach the database in question. Can it?

Yes it can, right now, after the backup was restored, the site is functioning properly

Then the new server settings - probably app pool settings are not the same then. In other words, all of the settings are not necessary in web.config files, but some things such as app-pool settings will have to be setup and configured with IIS, and such settings are outside of web.config. So, does app pool use a logon (impersonation) for rights to things such as folders etc? So, some settings are going to be in IIS, and not everything is in web.config. Do you have x32 bits turned on? (or do you even require x32 bit operation???). We don't have your computer, so we need vast more information.

We didn't change the settings in the IIS, we just changed the code from the latest publish to a backup previous to the latest.
32 Bit application is enabled

For the Identity our App Pool uses ApplicationPoolIdentity

Perhaps when using the publish option you try using the pre compile option.  Also,  is a security certificate being used, and perhaps it's not valid.  However I would try the pre compile option when you use the publish option from visual studio. You don't mention what publishing options you are using from visual studio
